# Meteor CPU usage > 100% on the client

Tags: performance, meteor, kadira

I have a meteor chat app that consumes >100% CPU **on the client side**. Server code runs smoothly.

[image]

Chrome profiler shows `program` uses that amount of CPU

[image]

Kadira CPU profiler shows nothing specific but regular low-level functions.

[image]

## How can I determine exact subs/methods that cause this huge CPU consumption?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'm gonna answer to my question. At least I have something to say.

At first look at this awesome Kadira debugger. They e-mailed me with the link, I hope they will announce it soon. What I can say is that it is more than you get with regular Chrome debugger.

https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-debug

At second I noticed that a huge amount of CPU consumption is related to guess what.. animated loaders/pre-loaders/progress-bars. In my case, to show/hide it smoothly I used `opacity:0` instead of `display:none`. It worked really well if not talking about CPU.